# make a redirect button in html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, random, redirect

Here is the code I am attempting to use and embed in a Google Sites page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Please follow the link below</title>
    <script>
    var urls = [
        "http://www.kittenwar.com/",
        'http://heeeeeeeey.com/',
        'http://eelslap.com/',
        'http://www.staggeringbeauty.com/',
        'http://www.omfgdogs.com/',
        'http://burymewithmymoney.com/',
        'http://www.fallingfalling.com/',
        'http://ducksarethebest.com/',
        'http://www.republiquedesmangues.fr/',
        'http://www.trypap.com/',
    ];

    function goSomewhere() {
        var url = urls[Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length)];
        window.location = url; // redirect
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

</body>



</html>
```

How do I make this work so that a button will appear in my Google Sites page that will randomly assign you to one of the listed array of links?

Answer (score 1):

By adding a simple button and calling the javascript function. And you need to do some adjustments in your google sites account. You can refer this link to do the changes accordingly in your account.

http://www.thelandscapeoflearning.com/2014/05/did-you-know-google-sites-no-longer.html

AND

https://help.mofuse.com/hc/en-us/articles/226313408-Redirect-Setup-Google-Sites

```js
 var urls = [
      "http://www.kittenwar.com/",
      'http://heeeeeeeey.com/',
      'http://eelslap.com/',
      'http://www.staggeringbeauty.com/',
      'http://www.omfgdogs.com/',
      'http://burymewithmymoney.com/',
      'http://www.fallingfalling.com/',
      'http://ducksarethebest.com/',
      'http://www.republiquedesmangues.fr/',
      'http://www.trypap.com/',
    ];

    function goSomewhere() {
      var url = urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)];
      window.location = url; // redirect
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Please follow the link below</title>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="goSomewhere();">Redirect</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. However, I'm finding that the button isn't working for redirects in Google Sites itself.

Comment: that is because of the security issues or some reason. But try some website which is not popular

Comment: https://help.mofuse.com/hc/en-us/articles/226313408-Redirect-Setup-Google-Sites please refer this to change the settings in your google sites

Answer (score 0):

In body

```
<button onclick="goSomewhere();">Click me</button>
```